# Standing Waves: finding the number of antinodes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, classical-mechanics

A string with a fixed frequency vibrator at one end forms a standing wave with 4 antinodes when under tension T1. When the tension is slowly increased, the standing wave disappears until tension T2 is reached with no resonances occurring between the two tensions. How many antinodes are there in this new standing wave?

There would be 8 antinodes, right? Because as you jump up to the next frequency, the number of antinodes doubles.

Actually, no, it would be 5 antinodes, right?

Comment: Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant equation to use for a standing wave string under some tension is:
$$ f_n = \frac{n}{2 L} \sqrt{\frac{F_T}{\rho}}$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density of the string and $F_T$ is the tension force.

For a fixed frequency we now have, after rearranging the above equation:

$$ F_{T,n} = \rho \left(\frac{2 L f_{\mathrm{fixed}}}{n}\right)^2 $$

When you increase the tension until you find a new standing wave pattern you must satisfy the above equation.

Remember that the letter n = 1 for the first standing wave pattern. If you have 4 antinodes then you have n = 4 in the above equation. The next standing wave pattern would be n = 5.